# Using codegen to generate java files for wsdl created by apache axis 1.4

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis, axis, wsdl2java

I have a WSDL which was generated by apache axis 1.4 I have been trying to use the axis2 codegen plugin for Eclipse to generate some java files but it is throwing errors saying that it's missing **axis2** types such as "org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean"

I was wondering if because the wsdl was generated using axis 1.4 and the java files using codegen which is axis2 - this is why it's giving me errors?

Is it possible to use codegen to generate java files for a wsdl created using apache axis 1.4?

appreciate your help, let me know if there's any information I can provide to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use WSDL2CODE to generate those files, it should work